# Как сделать так, чтобы бот реагировал на два префикса?

Tags: python, discord

Мне нужно чтобы бот реагировал на префикс Ok и префикс Okay

```
import random
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Ok ')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты спокойно можешь использовать массив для префиксов

```
import random
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['Ok ', 'Okay '])

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

        
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло